# What keys can I use to navigate Unity Greeter with a keyboard?

Tags: shortcut-keys, lightdm

I have a media center with a keyboard but no mouse. Is there a way I can navigate the Unity Greeter with a keyboard so I can change the session I log into, etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So far, it would seem you can 'navigate' the options using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, and confirm with <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd> or the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, but this is a bit wonky doesn't work very well yet.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> activates the **Screen Reader** while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> activates the **High Contrast display**.

Comment: And F10 opens the shutdown menu. But Tab does not work in the shutdown dialog in 11.10. That's fixed in 12.04 though.